# Initiate ApexPage.StandardSetController with List causes exception being thrown in later pagination calls

Tags: pagination, salesforce, soql, apex

I have a Paginated List displayed on the visual force page and in the backend I was using a StandardSetController to control the pagination. However, one column on the table is an aggregated field whose calculation is done in a wrapper class. Recently, I want to sort the paginated list against the calculated field. And unfortunately the calculated result cannot be done on the data model(SObject) level.

So I am thinking to passed a sorted list of SObject to the StandardSetController constructor. That is to sort the record before it has been pass into the StandardSetController.
The code is like below:

```
        List<Job__c> jobs = new List<Job__c>();
        List<Job__c> tempJobs = Database.Query(basicQuery + filterExpression);
        //sort with values
        List<JobWrapper> jws = createJobWrappers(tempJobs);
        JobWrapper.sortBy = JobWrapper.SORTBY_CALCULATEDFIELD_ASC;
        jws.sort();
        for(JobWrapper jw : jws){
            jobs.add(jw.JobRecord);
        }
        jobs = jobs.deepClone(true, true, true);

        StandardSetController con = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(jobs);
        con.setPageSize(10);
```

However after executing the last line system throw exception:**Modified rows exist in the records collection!**

I did not modify any rows in the controller. Could anyone help me understanding the exception?